# Using Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I came across this problem on FreeCodeCamp.org (link to the problem below) and I was wondering if someone could help me better understand why this equals 2 when calling with sum([2, 3, 4], 1);
I sat and looked at this for a bit but just feel blocked mentally in understanding how this works.
Simple developer trying to understand Recursion in Javascript.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks internet!

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  if(n <= 0){
    return 0;
  }else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}
sum([2, 3, 4], 1) // Returns 2
```

Here is a link to the problem: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/replace-loops-using-recursion

Comment: In the first iteration, `sum(arr, n - 1)` is `0` because `n - 1` is `0`. And `arr[n - 1]` is `2`.

Comment: Because you call `sum` with 1 as value of `n`, so it just picks only the first element from the array.

Comment: Quite short run first recursion ends with n==0 and returns also zero plus first array element  so 0+2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum(arr, n)` is a recursive function that returns the sum of the first `n` elements of an array `arr`.

In your example, you provide `sum([2, 3, 4], 1)` which basically says, compute the sum of the first element (i.e. the value of `n` in this example is `1`).

So it would go through the function as such...

```
// the first time through 
function sum([2, 3, 4], 1) {
  if(1 <= 0){ // false this time
    return 0; 
  }else { // this is where we end up
    return sum([2, 3, 4], 0) + 2; // sum will be the result of the recurse back into the function, plus 2
  }
}

// the second time through 
function sum([2, 3, 4], 0) {
  if(0 <= 0){ // true this time 
    return 0; // send this result back up to the first run through
  }else {
    // not relevant this time
  }
}

// back in the the first time through, 
// we now have a value to work with below
// remember, this isn't the 'third' time through,
// it is back in the first time run through
// just re-printed here so you could see 
// where the value gets returned from the second run
function sum([2, 3, 4], 1) {
  if(1 <= 0){ // false this time
    return 0; 
  }else { // this is where we end up
    return sum(0 + 2); // we got a result from the second run through, sum is now 2
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, just an aside... a neat trick some people can use to help wrap their heads around visualising recursion is to find the *end point* first and then work your way backwards up to the initial call. 

i.e. when does this recursion loop end? Right, got it, ok then, lets iterate back from there. While you do this, keep track of the result in a rough note off to the side to watch what is happening.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, with `n` equals to `1` is quite easy. Let's check step by step. Here your `sum` function; let's add some line to make it easier to refer:

```
1: function sum(arr, n) {
2:  if(n <= 0){
3:    return 0;
4:  }else {
5:    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
6:  }
7: }
```

Now, let's see what's happening step by step when you execute:

```
sum([2, 3, 4], 1)
```

The function `sum` is called with `arr` equals to `[2, 3, 4]`, and `n` equals to `1`.

Since `n` is not less or equals than 0 (*line 2*), we go to the `else` block, at line `5`.

Now, here is where the recursion happens: we call again the function `sum`, passing the same `arr`, but not the same `n`, instead we pass `n - 1`.

So we call `sum` again, this time with `arr` equals to `[2, 3, 4]` but with `n` equals to `0`.
Since `n` is `0` this time, at the *line 2* check we proceed to *line 3* and returns `0`.

Now, the function exit, with the value `0`, that we gave to the caller.

And the caller of `sum([2, 3, 4], 0)` was the execution `sum([2, 3, 4], 1)`, specifically at *line 5*:

```
5:    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
```

Since it returned `0`, we can imaging like:

```
5:    return 0 + arr[n - 1];
```

And remember that `n` is `1`, so:

```
5:    return 0 + arr[0];
```

Since `arr[0]` is equals to `2`:

```
5:    return 0 + 2;
```

And then why `sum([2, 3, 4], 1)` returns `2`.

I'm not sure if it's clearer now, but I hope so. :)

Answer (score 0):

`sum(arr, 1-1)` evaluates to 0 because of the if statement that checks if `n` is  <=0

and

`arr[n-1]` is equal to 2 as you are essentially trying to access the `arr[1-1]` which is `arr[0]`.

Therefore, it is returning 2 because `return sum(arr, n-1) + arr[n-1];` evaluates to 2.